# Alternative nonparametric test for chi-square test for independence

Tags: nonparametric, chi-squared-test, independence

Suppose we have a table like this:

\begin{array}{ |l | c | r |}
    \hline
      & \mathrm{win} & \mathrm{lose} \\ \hline
    \mathrm{male} & X_{11} & X_{12} \\ \hline
    \mathrm{female} & X_{21} & X_{22} \\
    \hline
  \end{array}

and we want to know if winning or losing depends on sex (male or female) apart from chi-square test for Independence, which non-parametric tests we can use?
Thanks

Comment: [Fisher's exact test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher's_exact_test)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a host of possibilities, though it depends on what exactly you intend by nonparametric; arguably all of these tests, including the chi-square are 'parametric'.

Some examples: You could use a two-sample proportions test (basically, normal approximation to binomial). You could do a two sample binomial test (the same thing, but based off the fact that the data are actually binomial). You could do a Fisher exact test (conditions on both margins, giving a hypergeometric).

Two sample proportions test:
http://www.statisticslectures.com/topics/ztestproportions/
http://stattrek.com/hypothesis-test/difference-in-proportions.aspx

Fisher exact test:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test